# Easy way to find whether the current user is accepted or rejected the Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to get all the Calendar events but only the events that current user not rejected. I do not see an straight forward way to get those unless I get all the attendees and see anyone rejected and thats the current user then remove those events.

I am just curious whether there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through [Google Calendar Events guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations), `attendees[].responseStatus` property accepts 4 possible values namely:

- **"needsAction"** - The attendee has not responded to the invitation.
- **"declined"** - The attendee has declined the invitation.
- **"tentative"** - The attendee has tentatively accepted the invitation.
- **"accepted"** - The attendee has accepted the invitation.

In your case, you can use **"accepted"** to indicate events that user did not reject.

Here's a list of [Quickstart Samples](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) to get you started immediately.